# What do the .ics and .vcs calendar file extensions stand for?

Tags: icalendar, vcalendar

I think that `.ics` stands for **Internet Calendar and Scheduling**. Is that correct?

I have no idea what `.vcs` stands for. Perhaps **Versit Consortium Specification** (the creators of vCalendar)?

Answer (score 2):

Re ics You may be right.  Googling doesn't clarify explicitly.
One site that I cannot find now said: ics = internet calendar subscription, but the RFC5545 spec talks about Internet Calendaring and Scheduling.

Re .vcs, given that the 'V' tend to indicate 'Virtual' it's more likely to be 'Virtual calendar'.  eg VCARD is Virtual card.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-or-subscribe-to-a-calendar-in-outlook-com-cff1429c-5af6-41ec-a5b4-74f2c278e98c